# StackExchange cookie for homepage

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

I believe that up until recently, stackexchange.com used to default to 'my tagged sets' page, rather than the default (hot questions) page.

If this was the case - was there a reason to change it? If not, can it be done - should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We no longer do this because we feel the homepage should not be dynamic -- that is, it should not be changing so radically based on your login status.

http://stackexchange.com

.. is now the same for every user, no matter whether they're logged in or not.

So if you want that page, bookmark it:

https://stackexchange.com/tagsets